# I have found out CDFs of 2 data and listed them. I need to find out the composition of such 2 CDFs

Tags: probability-or-statistics, distributions

```
x= RandomVariate[ExponentialDistribution[2], 10]
```

y = RandomVariate[ExponentialDistribution[3], 10]

```
f = EmpiricalDistribution[x]
```

fy = CDF[f, t] // PiecewiseExpand

```
g = EmpiricalDistribution[y]
```

fx = CDF[g, u] // PiecewiseExpand

```
`Want to find the composition fx of fy `
```

Comment: Is this what you are looking for: ``fz[z_] := CDF[f, CDF[g, z]]``?

Comment: Thank you, but not working.

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? I it giving the incorrect results? Does it throw an error?

Comment: Incorrect result, because fx and fy are the cdf of discrete random variable. I want the compostion of those cdf in piecewise expanded form. Your input composite the cdf form of a function

Comment: ``CDF[f, CDF[g, z]] // PiecewiseExpand``